# How to insert char in mathed lines in a file

Tags: linux, bash

For example, I have a file with the content:

```
{

  a : "apple"

  b : "orange"

}

{

  a : "meat"

}
```

I want to add "_1" in all the lines with "a : ", and get the result as:

```
{

  a : "apple_1"

  b : "orange"

}

{

  a : "meat_1"

}
```

Are there any ways by bash commands

Comment: Prefix your lines with four spaces.

Comment: Welcome! You are supposed to make some attempts to a solution before asking for help. What have you tried? Hints: `sed` and `awk` are appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spacing is unclear, whether you have `"a : ..."` or `"a: ..."`. You also have what appears similar to json, and if so, you need to use a json-aware utility to ensure the result is validated as valid json.

If however, it's just text, then `awk` can handle either case (`"a : ..."` or `"a: ..."`) for you by checking if the first field (or first and second in the case of `"a : ..."`) match your `a:` prefix. You then simply append `_1` to the end of the line to preserve leading spaces using the `sub` function on the entire line (e.g. `$0`). In all cases the line is output, either unchanged or with `_1` appended if your prefix is met.

You can do that with:

```
awk '$1=="a:" || ($1=="a" && $2==":") {sub(/"$/,"_1\"",$0)}1' file
```

(**note:** you can remove whatever side of the `||` isn't needed)

You can review the user of the `sub` function at [GNU awk - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `file`, the following results:

```
$ awk '$1=="a:" || ($1=="a" && $2==":") {sub(/"$/,"_1\"",$0)}1' file
{

  a : "apple_1"

  b : "orange"

}

{

  a : "meat_1"

}
```

**Using sed**

You can also accomplish the same thing with `sed` (which may be slightly more efficient in this case) using:

```
sed '/^\s*a\s:/s/"$/_1"/' file
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: For the `sed` version, maybe we can also support white spaces at the end. `sed '/^\s*a\s:/s/\("\s*\)$/_1\1/' file`

Comment: That's a good idea, I'm not sure you would want to keep it, but maybe you do. Sill need the `'"'` after the `_1` too.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Actually, it is a conf file parsed in the proto mode for a c++ binary. I want to run the binary repetitively in a script file, but I have to update the conf file firstly every time I run the binary. The content in {} is a repeated message.

Comment: Gotcha. It should work, If you need `"_1"` to be variable, that's doable as well, but you have to double-quote the `sed` invocation which means you will need to escape the `'"'` in the expression itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I have tried the sed command, it can not get the same result as awk. Is somewhere I am wrong?

Comment: If there is no space between the `"a:"`, then use `sed '/^\s*a\s*:/s/"$/_1"/' file` (see the extra `'*'`, to make the space optional - zero or more occurrences of a space) I get the exact same output as `awk` using either `sed` expression.